# Azure Stream Analytics job has validation errors: The input partition scheme is not defined properly

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-application-insights

I have created a stream based on the example in [Walkthrough: Export to SQL from Application Insights using Stream Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-code-sample-export-sql-stream-analytics/). Output is configured and tests OK. Query is defined and tests OK. Input (Data Stream) is configured to pull from Blob and tests OK, plus sample data works and gets JSON from BLOB successfully.  However, when I start the job I continue to get the error:

> The streaming job failed: Stream Analytics job has validation errors:
>   The input partition scheme is not defined properly.

How do I resolve this?

Inputs:

- Subscription, Storage Account, Key and Container are all correct.
- Serialzation: JSON
- Encoding: UTF8
- Path Prefix Pattern: analyticsAccount_xxx...xxxx/Event/{date}/{time}
- Date Format: YYYY-MM-DD
- Time Format: HH

Comment: Can you include the input configuration?

Comment: Sure - updated the question with input config.

Comment: And what is one example actual file path? What is the name of the container? You didn't include the container name in the path right?

Comment: Correct - file path in the container is: analyticsAccount_xxx...xxxx/Event/2015-07-26/10 - also, as stated in the question, the Input setup correctly pulls data from the BLOB when using the "Sample Data" option on the portal.